# Автоматизаця удаления любых параметров, классов из html

Tags: html

Есть большое количество html документов с рандомными классами и атрибутами в тегах. Необходимо их очистить и оставить только голые теги.

```
<p class="xxx" id="yyy">Текст</p> 
=> 
<p>Текст</p>
```

Каким образом я могу это сделать? Может можно регулярками это дело подчищать? Подскажите, буду признателен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно эта рекурсия вам поможет

```js
function deleteAttr (el) {
  for (let i = 0; i < el.children.length; i++) {
    Array.prototype.slice.call(el.children[i].attributes).forEach(function(attr) {
      el.children[i].removeAttribute(attr.name);
    });
    deleteAttr(el.children[i])
  }
}

deleteAttr(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0])
```